# MapReduce - How sort reduce output by value

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

How can I sort in decreasing order the reducer output by value?
I'm developing an application that must return top listened songs. Thus songs must be ordered by the number of listening.
My application works in this way:

```
Input: songname@userid@boolean
MapOutput : songname userid
ReduceOutput : songname number_of_listening
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I found this link informative as far as what's already done by Hadoop with respect to sorting: https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/map-reduce-secondary-sort-does-it-all/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html), Reducer output is not re-sorted.  Either sort the input to the reducer (if that works for your application) by setting an appropriate value for [JobConf.setOutputValueGroupingComparator(Class)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setOutputValueGroupingComparator(java.lang.Class)), or just sort the final output from the reducer in a separate step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorting input values for the reducer doesn't solve my problem. There's a way to start two jobs taking output of first as input of the second?

Comment: @highlycaffeinated is correct.  In your MR class that configures the mapper and reducer, just configure and submit a second job that points to the first job's output as the second job's input.  Be sure to use submitAndWait instead of just submit.

Comment: Thanks Chris. How can I do it? I must run both job from shell (one after the other), or there's a way to start both together?
I see Job API [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/index.html) and there are no methods to take a pre-fixed input.
Sorry but this is my first time working with hadoop.

Answer (score 6):

Best way to do it is to use the output of your first MapReduce job as the input of another job, which I call Sort.java. Since the Hadoop Map function has a sorting algorithm in place, you don't even need a reduce class. Just do something like this:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text>{
   private Text word = new Text();
   public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IO Exception, Interrupted Exception{
   String line = value.toString();
   StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
   word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
   IntWritable number = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
   context.write(number,word);
   }     
}
```

That will sort your [LongWritable,text] output of your first MapReduce by the LongWritable value. Let me know how it works!

CL

Comment: From Hadoop 2.4.0's Mapper class javadoc: "If the job has zero reduces then the output of the Mapper is directly written to the OutputFormat without sorting by keys." Doesn't this imply that your answer is actually incorrect?