# How to sort a custom writable type in Hadoop

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a custom type which contains fields of Hadoop native types (e.g. `Text` and `IntWritable`) and need to use it as a key and sort as I want during the shuffle/sort phase. There are similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343492/mapreduce-how-sort-reduce-output-by-value) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331722/how-to-sort-numerically-in-hadoops-shuffle-sort-phase), but they are about using native types. How to achieve the same results with the custom type, what requirements does it need to meet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are nuances to achieve this result, some are obvious, the others are not so. I'll try to explain them in a few short points:

1. First of all the custom type must implement [WritableComparable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html) instead of just [Writable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) and, of course, define `compareTo()` method.
2. Very important note from [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491901632):

   > All Writable implementations must have a default constructor so that the MapReduce framework can instantiate them, then populate their fields by calling readFields().

   And maybe the most error-prone part is that the default constructor should instantiate that fields (if they are not initialized), because they **must not** be null.
3. This point is about creating a custom comparator, if you are not satisfied with default sorting. In this case you need to create a new class, which extends [WritableComparator](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.html) and override its `compare()` method. After this you have two approaches of using this comparator instead of the default one: **or** you set this class to be used with the help of Job's [setSortComparatorClass](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setSortComparatorClass(java.lang.Class)) method:

   ```
   job.setSortComparatorClass(YourComparator.class)
   ```

   **or** register it in the static block of your custom type:

   ```
   static {  
       WritableComparator.define(CustomType.class, new YourComparator());
   }
   ```

   > The static block registers the raw comparator so that whenever  MapReduce sees the class, it knows to use the raw comparator as its default comparator.

[Here](https://github.com/Serob/Hadoop_ex/blob/master/H5/src/main/java/TupleWritable.java) is an example of such class with static nested comparator.